# Как вычислить интеграл на javascript?

Tags: javascript, библиотеки

Необходимо вычислить выражение :

```
N[Integrate[PDF[BetaDistribution[alpha1, beta1], x]
CDF[BetaDistribution[alpha2, beta2], x], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

Выражение решает задачу сравнения двух рекламных объявлений со стороны Байесовской статистики и вероятностного вывода.
Это формула записана в терминах Mathematica.
`N[expr]` — численно вычислить выражение expr.
`Integrate[f, {x, xmin, xmax}]` — интеграл функции f по х в интервале от xmin до xmax.
`PDF[dist, x]` — функция плотности вероятности для распределения dist в точке x.
`CDF[dist,x]` — функция распределения случайной величины для распределения dist в точке x.
`BetaDistribution[alpha, beta]` — непрерывное бета-распределение с параметрами `alpha`, `beta`.

В обычном виде это выглядит так: 
[image: Интеграл в обычном виде]

Нашла библиотеку, которая вычисляет `PDF` и `CDF` :https://github.com/jstat/jstat.
А вот с интегралом проблема.

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема с интегралом?

Comment: я не смогла найти библиотеку, в которой есть вычисление интеграла. и не совсем уверена в методе расчета

Comment: Вы всегда можете использовать метод Эйлера. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: Вы понимаете в чём состоит данный метод?

Comment: @Наталья Хенкина "...и не совсем уверена в методе расчета"-в чем Вы не уверены? Функция под интегралом имеет бесконечные полюса или не интегрируема по Лейбницу? В чем проблема? Увы, у меня сейчас нет времени ее исследовать.

Answer (score 4):

Здесь Вы можете найти библиотеку численных методов: http://www.numericjs.com/. Аналогичных библиотек довольно много по запросу `Численные методы JavaScript`.

Если она чем-то не нравится, то вполне можно ограничиться вычислением данного интеграла методом Эйлера: [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Метод_Эйлера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0). Этот алгоритм предельно прост. Вам необходимо задаться промежутком `[a, b] = [0, 1]`, выбрать шаг интегрирования `h = 0.01`, повторить в цикле формулу:

[image: Формула рассчёта]

Я привёл несколько равенств. Вам нужно вероятнее всего второе. Для этого необходимо держать в памяти на каждой итерации предыдущее значение. Последнее равенство не очень хорошо вычислять, так как вычисление функции `f` будет происходить дважды, что затормозит работу Вашего скрипта.

Таким образом, перебираете в цикле все значения из отрезка `[0; 1]` и получаете результат интегрирования в `y_n`.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать!